# OpenBSD LDAP authentication - ypldap high CPU usage

Tags: authentication, openbsd, ldap

I have an OpenBSD server with [login_ldap](http://ports.su/sysutils/login_ldap), ypldap, ypbind and portmapper is configured according to these guides that I managed to find courtesy of Google.

- http://obfuscurity.com/2009/08/OpenBSD-as-an-LDAP-Client
- http://blogs.helion-prime.com/2009/05/07/authorization-with-ldap-on-openbsd.html
- https://www.tumfatig.net/20160907/authenticate-openbsd-users-on-qnap-ldap/

For the remote LDAP users I have not found a way to create home dir automatically for the users, but the remote user can login to the OpenBSD server with no problems. If I create the home dir manually it seems to do the trick.

But I have a problem with ypldap. It seems that ypldap is accumulating connections to the LDAP server over time. Right after reboot there is only one established connection, but when the server has been running for some hours there is maybe 10-15 established connections and after 24 hours there might be 40-50. Somewhere during this the ypldap service is starting to use all awailable CPU. Since the server is not used for anything other than testing right now the "ypldap: ldap client" is using 99.9% of the CPU.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening, is it a config problem or likely a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try with OpenBSD 6.1/OpenLDAP 2.4.44, it works fine for me - when I updated to OpenBSD 6.2/OpenLDAP 2.4.45 I got same issue with ypldap, amount of ldap connections keeps growing and how fast depends of whats the ldap read interval value specified in ypldap.conf file. So this sounds like a bug for me.

Update, this was indeed a bug in OpenBSD 6.2 stable release. Big thanks to Stu from openbsd group who let me know about it. I took his advice and got it working. This is what he said: "A filedescriptor leak in ypldap was fixed after 6.2. If you have a CVS checkout of the 6.2 source tree, you could try updating just /usr/src/usr.sbin/ypldap to -current (change to the directory, cvs up -PdA) then rebuilding (make obj; make; doas make install)."

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply! I noticed the same behavior. When I changed the interval I got the same behavior as you did.